# Javascript - Sum/Total is reading NaN

Tags: javascript

I am making a pricing sheet that allows you to input the quantity of an item and will automatically calculate the cost. I have created the equations and now just need to add the results to give a total, which isn't working and displays a NaN error. Is it because the data is not formatted as numbers? Or is it something to do with the order that my functions are loading? I am new to JavaScript, any help would be great,
Cheers!

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
    <body>
        <p>Item 1</p>
        <input type="number" onkeyup="equation1() sum()" onkeydown="equation1(); sum()" value="3" id="box1">
        <p id="result1"></p>
        <div class="clear"></div>

        <p>Item 2</p>
        <input type="number" onkeyup="equation2() sum()" onkeydown="equation2(); sum()" value="1" id="box2">
        <p id="result2"></p>
        <div class="clear"></div>

        <p>Total</p>
        <p id="total"></p>
        <div class="clear"></div>

        <script>
            var x = document.getElementById("box1").value;
            var y = x * 6.23;
            var z = "$" + y.toFixed(2);
            document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = z;

            function equation1() {
                var x = document.getElementById("box1").value;
                var y = x * 6.23;
                var z = "$" + y.toFixed(2);
                document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = z;
            }

            var x = document.getElementById("box2").value;
            var y = x * 8.15;
            var z = "$" + y.toFixed(2);
            document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = z;

            function equation2() {
                var x = document.getElementById("box2").value;
                var y = x * 8.15;
                var z = "$" + y.toFixed(2);
                document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = z;
            }

            var price1 = document.getElementById("result1");
            var price2 = document.getElementById("result1");
            var x = +price1 + +price2;
            var z = "$" + x.toFixed(2);
            document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = z;

            function sum() {
                var price1 = document.getElementById("result1");
                var price2 = document.getElementById("result1");
                var x = +price1 + +price2;
                var z = "$" + x.toFixed(2);
                document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = z;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: just a suggestion... use jquery. It will make your code look much nicer

Comment: @kapetanios This can be written and expressed very easily without any libraries, the code is just very [WET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). jQuery isn't the answer to everything. Learning how to write regular JS is important.

Comment: @kapetanios: For someone new to JavaScript, suggesting to use jQuery is a pretty bad idea. Let him learn JS first.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that text content of the paragraphs needs to be read as `innerHTML` (or `textContent`). Plus you need to remove `$` sign from it before you perform math operation on them:

```
var price1 = document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML.replace('$', '');
var price2 = document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML.replace('$', '');
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/2vwqgkre/

Comment: May I suggest `parseFloat`

Comment: @vol7ron You can use parseFloat, but in this case it makes little difference compared to `+`, because you anyway need to remove `$`.

Comment: I stand corrected, it only makes sense to use *parseFloat* if the float is at the beginning of the string, not following the sigil (other than `+` or `-`); otherwise it would return `NaN`

Comment: Right, both `parseFloat` and `parseInt` stop parsing input on the first non-numeric character. If no number was found they return NaN.

Answer (score 0):

The result for this line 
`var price1 = document.getElementById("result1");`
is an `[object HTMLParagraphElement]`. You need first to get the innerHTML of it then you need to replace **$** sign to compute the value. So change your code to this :

```
<!doctype html>

<html>

<body>

<p>Item 1</p>
<input type="number" onkeyup="equation1() sum()" onkeydown="equation1(); sum()" value="3" id="box1">
<p id="result1"></p>
<div class="clear">
</div>
<p>Item 2</p>
<input type="number" onkeyup="equation2() sum()" onkeydown="equation2(); sum()" value="1" id="box2">
<p id="result2"></p>
<div class="clear">
</div>
<p>Total</p>
<p id="total"></p>
</div>

<script>

var x = document.getElementById("box1").value;
var y = x * 6.23;
var z = "$" + y.toFixed(2);
document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = z;

function equation1() {
var x = document.getElementById("box1").value;
var y = x * 6.23;
var z = "$" + y.toFixed(2);
document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = z;
}

var x = document.getElementById("box2").value;
var y = x * 8.15;
var z = "$" + y.toFixed(2);
document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = z;

function equation2() {
var x = document.getElementById("box2").value;
var y = x * 8.15;
var z = "$" + y.toFixed(2);
document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = z;
}

var price1 = document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML.replace('$', '');
var price2 = document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML.replace('$', '');
var x = +price1 + +price2;
var z = "$" + x.toFixed(2);
document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = z;

function sum() {
var price1 = document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML.replace('$', '');
var price2 = document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML.replace('$', '');
var x = +price1 + +price2;
var z = "$" + x.toFixed(2);
document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = z;
}

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late, but I hope it's correct. There were some mistakes. This is how I would do:

```
<script>
    function calculate() {
    var x = document.getElementById("box1").value;
    var y = x * 6.23;
    var z = "$" + y.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = z;

    var x = document.getElementById("box2").value;
    var y = x * 8.15;
    var z = "$" + y.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = z;
    sum();
    }

    function sum() {
    var price1 = (document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML).substr(1);
    var price2 = (document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML).substr(1);
    var x = parseFloat(price1) + parseFloat(price2);
    var z = "$" + x.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = z.toString();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="calculate();">
    <p>Item 1</p>
    <input type="number" onchange="calculate();" value="3" id="box1">
    <p id="result1"></p>
    <div class="clear">
    </div>
    <p>Item 2</p>
    <input type="number" onchange="calculate();" value="1" id="box2">
    <p id="result2"></p>
    <div class="clear">
    </div>
    <p>Total</p>
    <p id="total"></p>
    </div>
</body>
```

It is better because it reacts on changes and when the document is loaded.